# How get step count from background app using JobScheduler

Tags: android, background, android-sensors, android-jobscheduler, pedometer

The Android docs for the STEP_COUNTER sensor are a bit confusing.

According to this: [Android Sensor doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) I should always register the STEP_COUNTER sensor because otherwise the step counter sensor will not count at all. That is all fine and works as expected up until I think Android 10 when sensor events are no longer sent to background apps.

So then I tried to take the advice from [this other step counter doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion#sensors-motion-stepcounter) recommending using a JobScheduler to read the last value periodically. Now, afaik there is no way to get the latest value from a sensor, I must register a SensorEventListener as always.

So, now I tried to combine the two advices, always register the step counter sensor so the hardware sensor is counting then since I always get a fresh event when I register my listener, I tried to unregister and re-register this listener when the JobScheduler executed but I have not been able to get the latest step count when in background on my Pixel running Android 11 no matter what method I have tried.

I know we have Google Fit but for this specific scenario, using the basic step counter would be good enough if I could read out the latest value also when the JobScheduler runs as indicated in the documentation.

Anyone knows if this should still be possible or is it just that the docs are not updated?

Comment: I am currently dealing with this very same problem. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: No, I had to give up. The documentation at that point was contradicting. It sounded like it should work with JobScheduler but it seems all sensors are now blocked in background. I had to start using Google Fit instead. It works well but is much more work to set up and also requires the extra sign in by the user.

Comment: I feel you. The documentation has not improved, it is still contradicting and plainly suggesting JobScheduler (which we know is not enough). I have implemented something similar to what Alexey suggests with some success, using WorkManager. But still having some difficulties :'(

Answer (score 1):

Your app should be in foreground mode to get sensors data. Works for me with attaching foreground notification to worker (workmanager + setForegroundAsync). I think you solution will also work if foreground service  will be active.

Comment: Have you ever gone through SSG StepSetGo App? Even the app is killed and without the foreground service, they are showing the latest step count. How could they do this?